# Laravel 5.1 / Eloquent: How do I use a 3rd table to select from the second table

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have three tables: users, purchase_orders and approvals.

One **purchase_order** has to be approved by multiple users.

When a new **purchase_order** gets created, I also create 3 *pending* approvals belonging to that PO.

The **approvals** table has a field **allowed_user_type** that determines who can approve it.

I can't figure out, what is the Eloquent way of selecting the *pending* **purchase orders** that can be approved by a specific user, as these are determined from the **approvals** table.

---

So far I can pull the *pending* **approvals** from the approvals table for a user with the following in the User model.

```
public function approvals_pending()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Approval', 'allowed_user_type', 'user_type')
            ->where('approved', '=', 0);
}
```

The question is, how do I combine this with a theoretical filter?

I mean ideally, I would love to write:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\PO')->whereIn('id', '=', $this->approvals_pending()->get()->po_id);
```

Or something like that...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone interested I found a solution:

It's very close to what I thought I would have to write.

The *lists* method basically creates a single array out of the selected field, so it can be plugged-in directly to a *whereIn* method like so:

```
    return \App\PO::whereIn('id', $this->approvals_pending()->lists('po_id'));
```

I don't know if this is the most Eloquent way of doing this but it does work.